# Connected components problem

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $X$ a set and $p \in X$ a point, and define $\tau$ a topology as
> $$\tau := \{ A\subset X: p \in X-A \;\text{or}\; X-A\;\text{is finite}\}$$
> Find connected components $C(q)$ for every point $q\in X$.

Hi, I'm a little bit stuck on this problem because I got some trouble regarding point $p$. After successfully verifying that $\tau$ is actually a topology I also notice that for every $q \in X$ s.t. $q\neq p$ we have $\{q\} \in \tau$ and so $C(q) = \{q\}$. At first glance I think the same thing happen for $p$ - I'm very skeptical that this space is locally disconnected basically everywhere and not in $p$ but I don't know how to formalize -

Let $A$ the connected component of $p$ since is connected we cannot write $A$ as a disjoint union of open sets, but from here I don't know if there are two disjoint open sets or if something strange happens. Thank you for the help!

Comment: $\{q\}\in\tau$ on its own does not imply that $C(q)=\{q\}$.

Comment: For example, $\{0\}$ is open in the [Sierpenski space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000010), but the entire space is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eric Wofsey pointed out in the comments, knowing $\{q\}$ is open does not imply it is a component, in a general topological space.  A little more must be said, namely, that singletons are closed.  Fortunately, in our case, that is true, and so each $\{q\}$, $q\neq p$, is indeed a component, as $\{q\}$, being closed and open, forms a separation.

It then follows that $\{p\}$ is a component as well, since $C(p)$ must include $p$ and cannot include any $q\neq p$, as the components, being equivalence classes, are disjoint.  (More explicitly, observe that $X\backslash \{q\}$ is clopen for $q\neq p$, so $q\notin C(p)$.)

Comment: Thank you! I do not write that but I remember that another point of the exercise was: "prove that the space is $T_1$" said that the singletons are closed and we can proceed with our reasoning right?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt yes, exactly, once you have proved $T_1$ (which is almost an immediate consequence of the definition of $\tau$ and the definition of “closed”) then you can argue as in this answer.